# standard error in Weighted Least Squares in R

Tags: r, standard-error, weighted-regression

I am thinking of using a weighted least square method and checking the meaning of this approach. In particular, I am checking how the method in `lm(., weights = w)` matches the theoretical equation. The estimate can be calculated as follows:

$$ \hat{\beta} = (X'WX)^{-1}X'WY$$

I can get this value using the following code. But, I could not get the matched value of the standard error. In particular, I use

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 Var[\hat\beta|X] &= E[(X'WX)^{-1}X'We\cdot ((X'WX)^{-1}X'We)']\\
&= E[(X'WX)^{-1}X'We\cdot e' W' X (X'WX)^{-1}]\\
&= (X'WX)^{-1}X'WE[e\cdot e'|X] W' X (X'WX)^{-1}]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
If $E[e\cdot e'|X] = \sigma^2$, I would get `Case 1` on the following code. If I use $E[e\cdot e'|X] = \sigma_i^2$, I would get `Case 2`. Both cases does not match the result from the r function. How do I match this value?

```
x0 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

x1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)

x = cbind(x0, x1)

y = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

w = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

summary(lm(y ~ x1, weights = w)) # x1 Estimate: 5.0000     Std.Error: 1.0607

## By hand

n = length(x1)

k = ncol(x)

W = matrix(diag(w),ncol=n)

beta = solve(t(x) %*% W %*% x) %*% t(x) %*% W %*% y

mse = sum((y - t(t(beta) %*% t(x)))^2)/(n-k)

mse2 = c((y - t(t(beta) %*% t(x)))^2)

e = matrix(diag(mse2),ncol=n)

sqrt(mse * (solve(t(x) %*% W %*% x) %*% t(x) %*% W %*% t(W) %*% x %*% solve(t(x)%*%W %*% x))[2,2]) 
## Case1: Std.Error = 1

sqrt((solve(t(x) %*% W %*% x) %*% t(x) %*% W %*% e %*% t(W) %*% x %*% solve(t(x)%*%W %*% x))[2,2]) 
## Case2: Std.Error = 0.89
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step is applying the mathfact $\text{var}(AX) = A\text{var}(X)A^T$ for $A$ a constant and $X$ a matrix (or vector) of random variables. Using this you get:

$
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{var}(\hat{\beta}) &=& (X^TWX)^{-1}X^TW \text{var}(Y) WX(X^TWX)^{-1} 
\end{eqnarray}
$

And, if $W$ is selected so that $\text{var}(Y) = W^{-1} \sigma^2$, then

$
\begin{eqnarray}
&=& \sigma^2(X^TWX)^{-1} 
\end{eqnarray}
$

which one can show to be the best linear unbiased estimator (BLUE) as per Gauss Markov.,

You can replicate the output from LM modifying your code as below:

```
fit <- lm(y ~ x1, weights = w)
summary(fit) # x1 Estimate: 5.0000     Std.Error: 1.0607
sigma2 <- sum(w*fit$residuals^2)/{length(x0)-2}
xtwx <- t(x)%*%diag(w)%*%x
diag(solve(xtwx)*sigma2)^.5
```

Comment: I know this fact. I can't understand the meaning "if $W$ is selected so that $var(Y) = W^{-1}\sigma^2$." because $W$ is defined. And I think the first equation is the same as in my equation. This yields 1 or 0.89, which does not match 1.0607.

Comment: @hrkshr It is not the same as your equation, I'm afraid your derivation is too wrong to correct. For 1. there should be no "expectation" operator unless you're applying `var(x) = e(x^2) - e(x)^2`. Also $X$ is not random, or even if it was you already conditioned on the X in the LHS of your first display. Lastly, the variance of the $Y$ - conditional on $X$ - is not $e$, it is $\sigma^2$.

Comment: I see your point. But how do I match the value, which is the main question.

Comment: @hrkshr I provided the code snippet to address the problem.

Comment: Thanks. So, if $W$ is not selected so that $var(Y) = W^{-1}\sigma^2$, we should not use ```lm(., weight)```, right? And, to calculate ```sigma2```, we have to use ```w```?

Comment: @hrkshr the same issues apply as using an unweighted analysis; the beta is unbiased but probably inefficient, and the standard error is biased. If you are using a weight, and it might be wrong, you can try to use a robust sandwich estimator.